# Scheme: function, returning the list of numbers

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

Write a function `(pick-numbers-simple L)`.

`L` is a simple list, which does not contain nested lists.

The result of the function is a list of the numbers in `L`.

The appearance order of the numbers in the result list should be the same as that in `L`. For example, the result of `(pick-numbers-simple (list a b 1 2 c 3 d))` should be `(1 2 3)`.

I have a whole lot of them to write, i just need a head start. If I can get a help on this one, I can do the rest.

Comment: What part of "write a function in scheme" are you having trouble with?

Comment: First write a function that picks elements from a list based on an arbitrary predicate, then call that function and tell it to pick out the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on @Jerry Coffin's answer, and because the question tagged "homework", you could write `pick-numbers-simple` like:

```
(define (pick-numbers-simple xs)
  (let loop ((acc (list))
             (xs xs))
    (cond
      ((empty? xs)
       (reverse acc))
      ((number? (car xs))
       (loop (cons (car xs) acc) (cdr xs)))
      (else
       (loop acc (cdr xs))))))
```

Or using the function `filter`:

```
(define (pick-numbers-simple xs)
  (filter number? xs))
```

Example:

```
> (pick-numbers-simple (list 666 'foo 13 42 'bar))
(666 13 42)
```

Answer (score 3):

`number?` should tell you whether a particular item is a number.

Once you have that, it should be pretty simple: the return value is a list composed of the current item (if and only if its a number) followed the same function operating on the remainder of the list.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

http://see.stanford.edu/materials/icsppcs107/30-Scheme-Functions.pdf

And:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29